# How to find best match in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

I have a library of 1000 ORB object descriptors. I got a new image and want to get what object am I am looking at. How to do such thing in OpenCV - is there some out-of-the-box `i = matchDictionary(desriptors, currentDescriptor)` where i would be an index of best descriptor?

Comment: Sorry but there is no out of box method which would do the magic for you in OpenCV, but you try creating your own method, defining your own matching metric, you may start by analysing the color histogram, or template matching can also work fine if you have exact same patterns in your library and input image.

Answer (score 1):

For each object in your library you can match its object descriptors with your current descriptor using a [matcher](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d39/classcv_1_1DescriptorMatcher.html).

Then you can sum the distance of each [Dmatch](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/de0/classcv_1_1DMatch.html#a1cb9bee47b20ad96e16de28f4b9cbdf1)

The best object of the library is the one with the lowest distance.